# Extracting all Nouns from a CSV File Using NLTK

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I am new to both Python and NLTK. I would like to ask how can I extract all nouns from a list of sentences in CSV file using nltk?

the list of sentences is in CSV file and is in this form of:

```
  **Sentences**
```

1    I like to eat bread
2    I am excited to watch this movie
3    I sit on the bench and read my favorite book

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use pandas to change the CSV file to the DataFrame.(`pd.read_csv('filename')`)
Next thing is you have to play with NLTK. Here is the link to the [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html).